# How to get unique substring count from sqlite column?

Tags: sql, sqlite

From the data below , I would like to fetch the count of unique dates , ignoring the time value.

```
"01.09.2017 06.16"
"01.09.2017 06.17"
"01.09.2017 06.17"
"01.09.2017 06.32"
"26.10.2017 13.58"
"26.10.2017 13.59"
"26.10.2017 13.59"
"26.10.2017 14.02"
"18.01.2018 16.26"
"18.01.2018 16.26"
"18.01.2018 16.29"
"18.01.2018 16.29"
"18.01.2018 16.29"
"29.01.2018 15.45"
"29.01.2018 15.57"
"29.01.2018 15.57"
"29.01.2018 15.58"
"29.01.2018 15.58"
```

The resulting output for the sql query should be **4**

**Please ignore the double quotes, I have take this data from a column name PWhen and table name PData.**

Comment: This is not one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime). Anyway, just extract the first ten characters.

Comment: `count(distinct substring(...))`

Comment: @CL. I understand , I am looking for an alternative with like or substr approach.

Comment: You know one solution but want a different one? Why?

Comment: @jarlh syntax error and also unable to get the concept.

Comment: Take `count` of  `substring` till the first space and `group by` date

Comment: @Yunnosch I have got to know about the same via searching over the internet.

Comment: Please provide your sample data in SQLite digestible shape. I.e. `create table ...` and some `insert ..`

Comment: @Yunnosch I have made an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps you

```
  SELECT SUBSTR(PWhen,1,INSTR(PWhen,' ')),COUNT(*) from PDate GROUP BY
  SUBSTR(PWhen,1,INSTR(PWhen,' '));
```

To get the Unique list of dates

```
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SUBSTR(PWhen,1,INSTR(PWhen,' '))) from PDate;
```

Comment: can I order by SUBSTR(PWhen,1,INSTR(PWhen,' ')) this column ?

Comment: Yes you can @Prateek

Comment: `SELECT SUBSTR(ProcWhen ,1,INSTR(ProcWhen ,' ')),COUNT(*) from hana_data GROUP BY
  SUBSTR(ProcWhen ,1,INSTR(ProcWhen ,' ')) order by SUBSTR(ProcWhen ,1,INSTR(ProcWhen ,' '));` this sorts by the day value and doesn't take care of month.

Example 
`"01.09.2017 "
"01.10.2017 "
"01.11.2017 "
"01.12.2017 "
"02.01.2018 "
"02.10.2017 "
"02.11.2017 "
"02.12.2017 "
`

Comment: That is a new question. Also, compare CLs first comment.

Comment: @Yunnosch you are right. I have accepted the answer.

Comment: @Prateek: Ideally it should :) Not sure about your case

Comment: This lists the number of occurrences of each of the dates. It does not seem to be what you asked for. The desired output is the number of different dates, isn't it?

Comment: ' I would like to fetch the count of unique dates' - I guess he want to have the count of each dates in the column. I've worked on that guess

Comment: A plausible interpretation, especially because your answer got accepted. But the stated desired output is different. Not your fault Bibin. And I admit to being a little nitpicky here.

Comment: @Yunnosch you are right that is what I wanted but what the answer has provided also helped .

Comment: @Prateek: I have added the query to get unique list

Comment: @BibinMatthew yeah , I got it . Just the order by doesn't work. Anyways that was not in the scope of this question.

Comment: @BibinMatthew I have one more query , can I get support from you on the same ?

Comment: @Prateek Yeah, Please!

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the count of unique dates (4) for the sample input,
count the distinct dates, as reflected by the substring until the first blank.

```
select count(distinct substr(info, 1, instr (info,' '))) from strings;
```

Output:

```
4
```

MCVE I constructed from your syntax-free sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE strings (info varchar(20));
INSERT INTO "strings" VALUES('01.09.2017 06.16');
INSERT INTO "strings" VALUES('01.09.2017 06.17');
INSERT INTO "strings" VALUES('01.09.2017 06.17');
INSERT INTO "strings" VALUES('01.09.2017 06.32');
INSERT INTO "strings" VALUES('26.10.2017 13.58');
INSERT INTO "strings" VALUES('26.10.2017 13.59');
INSERT INTO "strings" VALUES('26.10.2017 13.59');
INSERT INTO "strings" VALUES('26.10.2017 14.02');
INSERT INTO "strings" VALUES('18.01.2018 16.26');
INSERT INTO "strings" VALUES('18.01.2018 16.26');
INSERT INTO "strings" VALUES('18.01.2018 16.29');
INSERT INTO "strings" VALUES('18.01.2018 16.29');
INSERT INTO "strings" VALUES('18.01.2018 16.29');
INSERT INTO "strings" VALUES('29.01.2018 15.45');
INSERT INTO "strings" VALUES('29.01.2018 15.57');
INSERT INTO "strings" VALUES('29.01.2018 15.57');
INSERT INTO "strings" VALUES('29.01.2018 15.58');
INSERT INTO "strings" VALUES('29.01.2018 15.58');
```

Comment: how to also get the matched strings in this query

Comment: Your comment is not clear about what you need. Would you like to make a separate question, show your desired output and explain more? A separate question will provide you with much better formatting features than a comment and more space. @PirateApp

Comment: how to get the output that says "2017 7 times", "2018 10 times"

Comment: @PirateApp Still unclear. Still a comment what should be a question. Please make a question. Use more words to describe in prose what you need. Show more combinations of sample input and desired output.

Comment: this is related to this question which is why I am not making another one as they ll shut it down saying its duplicate, my question was how can I get a count of all the years in the OP's data sample, 2017 appears 10 times and 2018 appears 12 times if you notice, how can I get an output with the years in 1 column and counts in another

Comment: You are explaining the difference quite well. I now understand the question and the difference to this one. It is not a duplicate. If on the other hand it IS a duplicate (i.e. I am wrong) then I misunderstand your question and the answer is here. Since I doubt it is a dupe, please, make a separate question. You can link to this question and spend a few words making sure that the difference is clear. I understand your question. Please make it one, otherwise where should I answer a question which is different form this one here?